# How class works in recursive function?

Tags: python

I recently work on the DPLL problem and I find an interesting situation. I cannot describe my question very well, but here is an example to show it.

**The first one is a recursive function without class.**

```
def test(my_list):
    print(my_list)
    variable1 = my_list[0]
    variable2 = my_list[1]
    variable3 = my_list[2]
    if sum(my_list) == 13:
       return True
    elif sum(my_list) == 11 or sum(my_list) == 12:
       return False
    if test(my_list+[variable1]) or test(my_list+[variable2]) or test(my_list+[variable3]):
       return True
    else:
       return False


test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
test(test_list)
```

And the result is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
```

So, we can find this function converts the list to former form if the function return false.

**The second one looks like this:**

```
class Formula(object):
    def __init__(self, clauses):
       self.clauses = clauses

    def add(self, variable):
       self.clauses.append(variable)
       return self


def test(formula):
    print(formula.clauses)
    variable1 = formula.clauses[0]
    variable2 = formula.clauses[1]
    variable3 = formula.clauses[2]
    if sum(formula.clauses) == 13:
        return True
    elif sum(formula.clauses) == 11 or sum(formula.clauses) == 12:
        return False
    if test(formula.add(variable1)) or test(formula.add(variable2)) or test(formula.add(variable3)):
        return True
    else:
        return False


test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
my_formula = Formula(test_list)
test(my_formula)
```

The result of this one is different:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

This function doesn't convert the list to the former form.

Why there is such a difference?

Comment: Please correct the indentation. Python programs are sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example you do `my_list+[variable1]`, which creates a new list that is the concatenation of `my_list` and `[variable1]`. This is also referred to as an "out-of-place" add. This creates a copy of the list which is passed down to the next invocation of the function.

In the second example you are `append`ing to the list instead (an "in-place" add). There is no copy created in this case, and there is only one list object used in the entire run of `test([1, 2, 3, 4])`